# ANTLR Match DateTIme in String

Tags: c#, antlr

I have written following grammar for parsing DateTime from a given string

```
datetime:  INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT4 
        | INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT4;

month:
    JAN
    | FEB
    | MAR
    | APR
    | MAY
    | JUN
    | JUL
    | AUG
    | SEP
    | OCT
    | NOV
    | DEC;


STRING: [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+;

NUMBER: [0-9]+;

INT4: DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
INT: DIGIT+;
DIGIT: ['0'-'9'];
DQUOTE  : '"';
JAN: [Jj][Aa][Nn];
FEB: [Ff][Ee][Bb];
MAR: [Mm][Aa][Rr];
APR: [Aa][Pp][Rr];
MAY: [Mm][Aa][Yy];
JUN: [Jj][Uu][Nn];
JUL: [Jj][Uu][Ll];
AUG: [Aa][Uu][Gg];
SEP: [Ss][Ee][Pp];
OCT: [Oo][Cc][Tt];
NOV: [Nn][Oo][Vv];
DEC: [Dd][Ee][Cc];

SEPARATOR: '-';
WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;
```

When I am trying to match the following string

```
new teatime at 23-SEP-2013 for Santosh Singh and 3 guests
```

I am getting the following error in ANTLR output

```
line 1:15 mismatched input '23' expecting INT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `DIGIT: ['0'-'9'];` rule is incorrect, it should be: `DIGIT: [0-9];`

Whenever you get unexpected results, start by dumping the tokens your lexer is creating to see if they are the tokens you expect your parser to work with. For your grammar, that would be the following tokens:

```
STRING                    `new`
STRING                    `teatime`
STRING                    `at`
NUMBER                    `23`
SEPARATOR                 `-`
STRING                    `SEP`
SEPARATOR                 `-`
NUMBER                    `2013`
STRING                    `for`
STRING                    `Santosh`
STRING                    `Singh`
STRING                    `and`
NUMBER                    `3`
STRING                    `guests`
```

As you can see, there are a couple of things going wrong:

1. no `INT` tokens are ever created, while your parser expects such tokens. This is because of the following rules (and their order):

```
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
INT4   : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
INT    : DIGIT+;
DIGIT  : [0-9];
```

For the input `3`, the rules `NUMBER`, `INT` and `DIGIT` could be matched. Whenever ANTLR's lexer can construct more than 1 token, the token (lexer rule) defined first "wins". So, a single digit token, or any amount of digit token, will always become a `NUMBER` token. `INT4`, `INT` and `DIGIT` will never be created, no matter if the parser is trying to match any of these tokens. The lexer works independently from the parser. Nothing you can do about that.

2. the months are never matched, they're all `STRING` tokens. The same as with the issue above: `"SEP"` can be matched by the `STRING` rule and by the `SEP` rule, but since `STRING` is defined before `SEP`, the one defined first "wins".

Reordering the grammar a bit like this:

```
grammar T;

parse
 : (datetime | text)+ EOF
 ;

text
 : STRING
 | month
 | INT
 ;

datetime
 : INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT4
 | INT SEPARATOR month SEPARATOR INT4
 ;

month
 : JAN
 | FEB
 | MAR
 | APR
 | MAY
 | JUN
 | JUL
 | AUG
 | SEP
 | OCT
 | NOV
 | DEC
 ;

JAN : [Jj][Aa][Nn];
FEB : [Ff][Ee][Bb];
MAR : [Mm][Aa][Rr];
APR : [Aa][Pp][Rr];
MAY : [Mm][Aa][Yy];
JUN : [Jj][Uu][Nn];
JUL : [Jj][Uu][Ll];
AUG : [Aa][Uu][Gg];
SEP : [Ss][Ee][Pp];
OCT : [Oo][Cc][Tt];
NOV : [Nn][Oo][Vv];
DEC : [Dd][Ee][Cc];

STRING    : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+;
INT4      : DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
INT       : DIGIT+;
DQUOTE    : '"';
SEPARATOR : '-';

WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> skip;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
```

should match your input correctly.